# How to get or make gitian key to build bitcoin

Tags: bitcoin

Do anyone know how to get or make a gitian key so that I can use it to build bitcoin in different platform from source code using gitian builder?

In gitian process doc, it mentions the setup script to run:

```
pushd ./bitcoin
 export SIGNER=(your Gitian key, ie bluematt, sipa, etc)
 export VERSION=0.13.0
 git fetch
 git checkout v${VERSION}
 popd
```

Comment: please post this to bitcoin stack overflow, I am interested in this too

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/bitcoin-core/gitian.sigs

> This repository contains Gitian signatures for releases and release
> candiates of Bitcoin Core.
>
> **How to Make and Submit Gitian Sigs**
>
> See the Bitcoin Core Gitian documentation and the Bitcoin Core Release
> Process for instructions on Gitian building. You might have to use the
> release process of the tag that you are building.